# Creating div with width equal to height

Tags: css

I've been stuck on this for awhile now. I have an answers-container div that's going to contain 4 rows, each with a checkbox and a button like this.

[image]

The problem is, I can't figure out how to get the width of the checkbox to be the same as the height, since if I set answers-container to be a grid and do grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25% the height of each answer will be correct but there's no way to set the width to be the same as the height. I know it's possible to do this in Jquery by manually grabbing the value of the height, but if possible I would like to find a solution in CSS.

I saw an answer that used a dummy div with padding set to a percentage which inherits that percentage from the parent, but I couldn't figure out a way to get that method to work while still keeping the button divs next to the checkboxes.

I don't have much code to share because I've deleted and rewritten this so many times, but this is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/QWvWOgz

And this is what I'm trying to do:

```
.answers-container {
    grid-columns: 2/3;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}

.answer {
    
}

.checkbox {

}

.button {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .container {
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      padding-top: 50%;
      /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
    }
    
    .text {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      1:1 Aspect ratio<br/> width and height are always equeal
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Again this method isn't working for me. I updated my codepen with that method to show:

.answer-1 {
    grid-rows: 1/2;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 100%;
}

.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}